# Does pure water freeze at the same temperature even if there are a mix of gases in the environment?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, water, freezing

For example water has a triple point at 670 Pa c.ca.at 0.01°C
Could she freeze at this temperature even if there is another gas in the mixture of the vapour,for example He4 at 1Atm? Does the Rault law tell us something in this aspect of phase change of a mixture,from liquid to solid?

Comment: At 1 atm total pressure, the freezing point is 0.0 C, as compared with 0.01 C at the triple point.  So, yes, in the gas phase, the presence of other gases which change the total pressure affect the freezing point a little.

Comment: Even the isotopic composition of hydrogen and oxygen will change the temperature.

Comment: Is this statement true? I put some sea water in a closed bottle and with an hose i let the water vapor liquify in a bottle 250 down.